# vecintrin.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, vectorization

While building TensorFlow with vectorization, I get below error:

> external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/../../../Eigen/Core:248:27:
>   fatal error: vecintrin.h: No such file or directory compilation
>   terminated.

I don't see this on Ubuntu 17.04 (GCC v6.3.0), however it is appearing on Ubuntu 16.04 (GCC v5.4.0).

Is it related to GCC version? or some dependency is needed?

Comment: Compile with `g++ -H` on the working Ubuntu to see what header is included

Comment: Located it here: /usr/lib/gcc/s390x-linux-gnu/6/include/vecintrin.h, so looks like I will have to upgrade gcc version to enable vectorization.

Comment: You are cross-compiling for an IBM mainframe?

Comment: Compiling on s390x itself.